# Schema.xml is not created in the core directory

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I was following this article to start with my apache solr expedition. 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-solr/apache-solr-tutorial-beginners/ 
I have created a solr core using below command-

```
> solr create -c mycorename
```

This has created a core but schema.xml file is not created inside the conf directory. Instead of this i am able to see managed-schema.xml file. Does this command create a schemaless core. Please let me know how i can create a core that also have a schema.xml file created in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i've got some issue. 
Shortly. Solr can use ether static schema, or dynamic (REST api) schema. So, you should select which one you'll use.
You can do id in solrconfig.xml

Like this:

`<schemaFactory class="ManagedIndexSchemaFactory">
   <bool name="mutable">true</bool>
   <str name="managedSchemaResourceName">managed-schema</str>
 </schemaFactory>`

More info, read this [guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Schema+Definition+in+SolrConfig)

Comment: 1. This guide does not explain how do solr create a schema.xml file while creating a core. or is it not possible to create a schema.xml file since solr 5.x.x.  Instead of managed-schema.xml file i need a editable schema.xml file auto generated by solr, as referred in most of the documents.

Comment: Copy basic_config to a new folder. Go into this new folder's conf folder. Copy managed-schema to schema.xml. Edit this schema.xml as you wish but be careful of some news tag and format in case you modify this according some old-version schema.xml. Then issue bin/solr -c corename -d xxx where  xxx is the path to new folder.